# How to ban google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Someone is using google app engine to crawl through my site. Is there any way to ban the google app engine to prevent this? I don't want to let user cache the data from my site.

Is there a complete ip which google app engine uses? That will help developers be able to stop being from stolen from.

Comment: I guess the support forum for GAE is a better place to ask for their IP range.

Comment: Look at the User-Agent header in the incoming request. That'll give you both indication that the request is coming from App Engine, and it will give you the ID of the app, should you wish to be more selective about who you're blocking. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview for details.

Answer (score 4):

You can check the User Agent of the request for AppEngine-Google and deny those requests. More info about the request header can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview#Request_Headers